# MATLAB Display a figure stored in a structure

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I stored a figure in a structure:

```
A.my_fig = gcf;
```

How do I 'reopen' or 'display' this figure? I tried `openfig('A.my_fig')` but it did not reopen the figure.

**EDIT:**

To make it clear, I've a function:

```
function my_fig = gen_fig(x)
my_fig = figure
h = plot(x)
close(my_fig)
end
```

After calling the function, I would like to be able to display the figure. I don't want the figure to be stored as a file, I want it to be stored inside a variable. Is this possible?

Comment: That function should already plot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By closing a figure you are **deleting** (invalidating) the figure handle returned by `gcf`. The `gcf` object (handle) is thus **invalid** and can't be operated on.

`openfig` is for opening figures that have been stored in a `.fig` file with for instance [`hgsave`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hgsave.html). Instead of storing the figure handle returned by `gcf` you should save the figure as `.fig` file and then open it again with `openfig`.

Example:

```
h = figure;
y = randi(10, [4 3]);
bar(y);
hgsave(h, 'test'); % Saves the figure given by h as test.fig
close(h); % Closes the figure window and invalidates the h object
```

Now we can open the figure with `openfig('test')`.

---

To clarify, there is no way to store a MATLAB figure in a variable, close the figure and then reopen it from that variable. The closest possible solution would be to save the figure to a `.fig` file, close it, reopen it and then delete it.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I understand. However, this is not exactly what I was looking for... I updated my post, have a look please.

Comment: @mat When you return from the function the figure will still be open as you never call close. You can bring it to to focus with `my_fig = gen_fig(x); figure(my_fig);`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @mat There is no way to store a figure in a variable, close it and reopen it from a variable. The closest you could get is to save it, close it, open it and then delete it. However, I'm having a hard time understanding your question with the edit.

Comment: Exactly, I was trying to store a figure in a variable, close it and reopen it from a variable. I wish this was possible, thank you anway!

Comment: I've a function which generates a figure, however I dont want it to display it right now, I want to be able to display it whenever I wish. And this without creating an extra file in my library...

Comment: @mat Ok. A solution may be to split the generation of data and the displaying of the actual figure into 2 functions and only calling the display function when you need.

Comment: I thought about it, but it wans't exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

That is not how figure handles work.

Figure handles are a programmatic "item" that links the code to the opened figure.

This means that if the figure is closed, the handle disapears. You can easily see that by

```
surf(peaks);
A=gcf;
close(gcf);
A
```

gives:

```
A = 

  handle to deleted Figure
```

Instead, what you can do is save the figures in `.fig` format. That will allow you to read and plot them later, using `openfig`